# Oracle catsearch and CTXSYS.CTXCAT index are not working as expected

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql

I have a table in an Oracle database which contains several million records,
The DML commands that are being executed on this table are mainly INSERT (without DELETE / UPDATE),
This table is being queried by a text parameter on a specific column,
I tried to tune the performance of this query by adding a CTXSYS.CTXCAT index and use the catsearch function as below, 
But actually the catsearch function doesn't return the expected results:

-- first, create an emp table with dept column and a random search string

```
create table emp as
select rownum id , 'Employee ' || to_char(rownum) name , MOD(rownum,20) + 1 dept , dbms_random.string('A', 50) search_string
from dual
connect by level <= 1000000;
```

-- then, create 2 indexes - one for the catsearch function, and another regular index

```
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_index_set('emp_iset');
  ctx_ddl.add_index('emp_iset','dept'); /* sub-index A */
end;

CREATE INDEX EMP_FULLTEXT_IDX ON emp(search_string) 
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT 
  PARAMETERS ('index set emp_iset');

create index emp_search_string_idx on emp(search_string);
```

now, I would expect that the following queries will return the same results, but unfortunately, they don't:

```
select count(*) from emp where dept = 10 and lower(search_string) like '%test%';

select count(*) from emp where catsearch(search_string, 'test', 'dept = 10') > 0;
```

also, a minus query between the 2 options of the query return some results :

```
select * from emp where dept = 10 and lower(search_string) like '%test%'
minus
select * from emp where catsearch(search_string, 'test', 'dept = 10') > 0;
```

I tried looking up for the documentation of the catsearch function and the CTXSYS.CTXCAT index, but no luck yet,
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wildcards.

```
select count(*) from emp where catsearch(search_string, '**test*', 'dept = 10') > 0;
```